# How to replace the values of an array with other elements in swift3?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I have an array A which contains 2 arrays :

```
[[Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday], [Monday, Wednesday]]
```

Now i want to replace the elements of array A with:

```
[[Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat], [Mon, Wed]]
```

For this i am planning to use:

```
for days in operatingDays {
  for weekdays in days
  {
  if (operatingDays[i] as? String == "Sun") {
    operatingDays[i] = "Su"
  } else if operatingDays[i] as? String == "Mon"{
    operatingDays[i] = "Mo"
  } else if operatingDays[i] as? String == "Tue"{
    operatingDays[i] = "Tu"
  } else if operatingDays[i] as? String == "Wed"{
    operatingDays[i] = "We"
  } else if operatingDays[i] as? String == "Thu"{
    operatingDays[i] = "Th"
  } else if operatingDays[i] as? String == "Fri"{
    operatingDays[i] = "Fr"
  } else if operatingDays[i] as? String == "Sat"{
    operatingDays[i] = "Sa"
  }
}
}
```

But it is showing the error:
[image]
But how to implement this in Swift3 any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Show us what did you try so far and what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: Its the same issue from your previous question you need to cast days to [String]

Comment: You need to tell the compiler that `days` is an Array and not a object of type ANy.

Comment: Why the long if-block? Just use `substring` to get the first three characters of the original string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var input = [["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"], ["Monday", "Wednesday"]]

var output = [[String]]()

for array in input {
    output.append(array.map {String($0.characters.prefix(3))})
}
```

the output will contain `[["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"], ["Mon", "Wed"]]`

Comment: It is showing value of Type any has no member "Map"

Comment: You must specify that it is an array, for example with `as? [String]`

Answer (score 2):

Cast `operatingDays` as something more specific

```
for days in operatingDays as! [[String]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `AnyObject` type for casting your array, for example this code could be help you:

```
var array: [AnyObject] = [[Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday], [Monday, Wednesday]]
array = [[Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat], [Mon, Wed]]
```

Now if you want to do something special, you must cast that array:

```
if let item = array[2] as? String{
    print(item)
}
```

Or you simply print your array:

```
for item in array{
    print("my item is \(item)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this, as I said you need to cast days as `[String]`

```
for days in operatingDays {
        if let daysArray = days as? [String]
        {
            for weekdays in daysArray
            {
               operatingDays[i] = 
                if (operatingDays[i] as? String == "Sun") {
                    operatingDays[i] = "Su"
                } else if operatingDays[i] as? String == "Mon"{
                    operatingDays[i] = "Mo"
                } else if operatingDays[i] as? String == "Tue"{
                    operatingDays[i] = "Tu"
                } else if operatingDays[i] as? String == "Wed"{
                    operatingDays[i] = "We"
                } else if operatingDays[i] as? String == "Thu"{
                    operatingDays[i] = "Th"
                } else if operatingDays[i] as? String == "Fri"{
                    operatingDays[i] = "Fr"
                } else if operatingDays[i] as? String == "Sat"{
                    operatingDays[i] = "Sa"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @ChelseaShawra i am working in improving this code, i think with map can be solved in more shorty way as is showed in the accepted answer